# Multiple Excel files using SSIS

Tags: excel, ssis, ssms

I created a SSIS package to read multiple excel files from folder and load to sql table. I have set up a sql job to run every week. But, everytime the job is running data from the previous loaded excel files are loading into sql table again resulting duplicate records in the table.

One thing I can do is remove the old files after loaded, but is there anyway to not pick old files. I used aggregate to eliminate duplicate records in the excel file.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The only way to not pick old files is to know which files have been picked, and the easiest way to do that is move them to another folder. This has many other benefits, like making it externally obvious which files have been imported

Comment: As @Nick.McDermaid pointed out, that's the best way to go about processing files. Have folders such as input, archive, error and move the files to appropriate folders post processing. Another way for you to ensure the same files aren't read is to suffix the filenames after they are processed with say _Archive and tweak the foreach loop logic to exclude such files.

Comment: Can we give a archive folder path pointing to another remote server.

Comment: Sure. You should try irt and see. You just use a UNC (ie. `\\servername\share\folder`). Do you just run this package interactively (from visual studio) or do you schedule it?

Comment: From visual studio

Comment: Sorry i am scheduling a sql job for it

Comment: Well you'll need to do both - run it in VS and schedule it. So you've asked a lot of question but you haven't actually tried anything